# Build android application with a library using ant

Tags: android, ant, android-build

I have 2 projects ( source code) . The project A is the library uncompiled and the project B uses that library. I want to compile that using ant. I'm using android update to setup like that.

> android update  lib-project --target 2 --path c:\Android-Build\A
>
> android update  project --target 2 --path c:\Android-Build\B --library ..\A

In the libs folder of the project B i don't have anything. All the libraries i'm using are on the library (A). Using eclipse everything comes out normally.

How can i do that compiling using ant.

ant debug throw errors . The library (A) compiles first ( bin and gen folders are generated).

But when comes to the project B to get compiled cannot find the imports from the library.
How can i tell ant to include the library to the project B during its build proccess? ty.

> [javac] C:\Android-Build\B Activity.java:7: error: cannot find
>   symbol
>       [javac] import com.a.A;

****UPDATE*****

---

`project.properties` for project B.

```
android.library.reference.1=..\\A
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:13
```

---

`project.properties` for project A.

```
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:13
```

the \\ seems to be correct because if i change it to \ ant cannot find the library

Comment: Please add `project.properties` for B project.

Comment: Hm, nothing wrong here. Please also add `project.properties` for A project.

Comment: Also added. I don't think it has anything to do with the property files. When i build the project B library A gets compiled but B don't include that library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add next line to your A's `project.properties` file:

```
android.library=true
```